# ReactJS changing page content through an array of content components by click event

Tags: reactjs

I stored content component of 4 pages in an array. And I want after clicking next button(in footer component), page layout will render the next content component in the array, does anyone have an idea for that?

Many thanks! Here are my files

```
**** Content.jsx ****
import React from 'react';

import Start from './Start.jsx';
import Time from './Time.jsx';
import Information from './Information.jsx';
import End from './End.jsx';

export default class Content extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const Contents = [ <Start />, <Time />, <Information />, <End /> ];

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {Contents[0]}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

**** Footer.jsx ****
import React from 'react';

import Content from './Content.jsx';

export default class Footer extends React.Component {

    render(){
        const button = {
            margin: "10em 1em 0 1em"
        };
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={button}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" style={button}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to have an array position to know what to transition to.

so in your footer you want to know what the index is and you want to pass the click event through to a parent component to handle the data transfer

```
export default class Footer extends Component {
    viewNext(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.setContent(this.props.currentIndex + 1);
    }
    viewPrevious(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.setContent(this.props.currentIndex - 1);
    }
    render(){
        const button = {
            margin: "10em 1em 0 1em"
        };
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={button} onClick={this.viewPrevious.bind(this)}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" style={button} onClick={this.viewNext.bind(this)}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

now, when you are rendering the footer you want to pass through the relative info

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {currentIndex: 0};

        this.setContent = this.setContent.bind(this);
    }
    setContent(index){
        this.setState({currentIndex: index});
    }
    render(){
        let {currentIndex} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Content currentIndex={currentIndex}/>
                <Footer setContent={this.setContent} currentIndex={currentIndex}/>
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

finally in the content component you need to accept this index and use it as well

```
export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.componentsArr = [ <Start />, <Time />, <Information />, <End /> ]; // I moved this array to the constructor so this way you aren't creating it every single render. just need to make it once.
    }
    render(){
        const ViewComponent = this.componentsArr[this.props.currentIndex];
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {ViewComponent}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**So here is some homework for you**. Add validation on viewing the next component or the previous. meaning what happens when you are viewing the last component (`<End />`) and you click the next button? Hint: You need to move the componentsArr logic to App as well and pass its length to the footer for index position purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! When I try to run, it said unexpected token "=" at the line "setContent **=** (index) => {" in class App

Comment: @user6535149 what does that mean to you? you should be able to figure out what that means and not need me to tell you. its an arrow function that is in es6 syntax. it looks like your transpiler is not setup to work with class methods as arrow functions. I edited to make it runnable code with your transpiler, but you shouldn't have needed me to do that. you just bind your context instead of using an arrow function.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much. I am new to reactjs and es6 and I will try to figure it out the rest and the validation as you mentioned. Thank you for taking time to help me :D

Comment: @user6535149 no worries just trying to help you think critically :) I can answer more questions you have if you have any! Also if this fixed your issue I'd greatly appreciate it if you can mark it as accepted :D

Comment: Yes thank you for your help and kindness :D The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In parent component of both Content and Footer add a method setActiveContent.

class Parent extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       activeContent: ''
    }
  }
  setActiveContent(contentId) {
    this.setState({
        activeContent: this.state.activeContent + contentId
    });
  }

  render(){
     <div>
       <Content activeContent={this.state.activeContent}/>
       <Footer setActiveContent={this.setActiveContent}/>
  }
}


export default class Footer extends React.Component {

    handleClick() {
      this.props.setActiveContent(1);
    }
    render(){
        const button = {
            margin: "10em 1em 0 1em"
        };
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-secondary" style={button}>Back</button>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-success" style={button}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default class Content extends React.Component {
    render(){
        const Contents = [ <Start />, <Time />, <Information />, <End /> ];

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {Contents[this.props.activeContent]}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! But it came out an error : can't read property "activeContent" of null.

Comment: this was overview of code ,you need to add state in the constructor